# Analysis of first order differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I'm working through a question where the differential equation is

$$ y^2(y'^2 -1)(3y'^2 +1) = c, \;\;\; y(0) = 0 $$

and the answer proceeds with two cases

(1) $c=0 \implies y(x)=0 \vee y(x) = \pm x$

(2) $c\neq0 \implies \lim_{x\to 0} y^2y'^4 = c/3$

I'm fine with (1), but I can't see how to get (2). I've tried multiplying out the brackets and eliminating terms involving $y$ only, but that doesn't get the answer so far as I can see. I'm not very familiar with how to manipulate limits, especially in the context of differential equations, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Is it from a book? which book, page etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $x=0$, $y$ is very small, so $y'$ must be large if $c\neq0$. If $y'$ is large then the terms in brackets will approximate to $3y'^4$.

Comment: thankyou. That does make sense, in fact it's "common sense". For your first sentence is there a formal result along the lines of $\lim_{p\to0} pq \neq 0 \implies q\to\pm\infty$? The other result I'm aware of that's relevant here is $\lim pq = \lim p\lim q$ -- which is also common sense.